# Calculating difference ratios (Δβ/Δρ) from a data set

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, excel

I am little bit confused about how to calculate `δβ/δρ` value if I have set of values like this.

I have the values of β and ρ like this.

```
β          ρ

0,324     0,687
0,322     0,695
0,319     0,721
0,317     0,759
0,316     0,798
```

aka:

```
β={0.324, 0.322, 0.319, 0.317, 0.316};
ρ={0.687, 0.695, 0.721, 0.759, 0.798};
```

from the above set of values I would need to calculate `δβ/δρ`.

Can anyone explain me how to do it with *Mathematica*?

Comment: This is a Mathematica related site so people can tell you how to do it in Mathematica not "in microsoft excel or normal method"...

Comment: @Öskå I'm not convinced that your edit (specifically, where you changed it from asking for an Excel solution to a *Mathematica* one) was a good idea. If the OP isn't interested in *Mathematica*, I'd argue that it's better to close the question as off topic than to change it so that people end up answering a question that nobody actually asked. This ends up being a waste of time for both the OP and the answerers.

Comment: I just assumed that "or other method" meant "or other software" since he just talked about Excel. And some new users might find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 5):

How about using the basic definition.

```
δβ/δρ = (β2-β1)/(ρ2-ρ1)
```

Since you have 5 data points,

```
β = {0.324, 0.322, 0.319, 0.317, 0.316};
ρ = {0.687, 0.695, 0.721, 0.759, 0.798};
ndata = 5;
grad = Table[(β[[i + 1]] - β[[i]])/(ρ[[i + 1]] - ρ[[i]]), {i, 1, ndata - 1}];
(* # of data for δβ/δρ will be ndata-1 *)
ListLinePlot[{Table[{ρ[[i]],β[[i]]},{i,1,ndata}],Table[{ρ[[i]],grad[[i]]},{i,1,ndata-1}]}, AxesLabel -> {"ρ", "β, δβ/δρ"}]
```

[image: grad]

#### Further simplification

As Öskå pointed out it can be done even more simply.

```
β = {0.324, 0.322, 0.319, 0.317, 0.316};
ρ = {0.687, 0.695, 0.721, 0.759, 0.798};
grad = Differences[β]/Differences[ρ];
ndatabeta=Length[β]; ndatagrad=Length[grad];
ListLinePlot[{Table[{ρ[[i]],β[[i]]},{i,1,ndatabeta}],Table[{ρ[[i]],grad[[i]]},{i,1,ndatagrad}]}]
```

Now you can use `ndatabeta` and `ndatagrad` as the number of data for your individual `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Or simply `grad=Differences@β/Differences@ρ`

Comment: Thanks @Öskå. Looks like I am yet to overcome my Fortran-gia.

Comment: @Sumit. Something seems to be a problem here. Based on the data shouldn't the magnitude of the slopes be decreasing?

Comment: @Sumit. I see you have used $\beta$ on the x-axis. I think it would be more natural to use $\rho$. Only the slopes in this answer appeared to have a different trend, and that had thrown me off.

Comment: Thanks @SubaThomas for pointing out. I have corrected that. It is just a result of my tendency to consider the first column as `x`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Interpolation` that will give `β=fun[ρ]`

```
fun = Interpolation[Transpose[{ρ, β}]];
Plot[Evaluate@{fun[t], fun'[t]}, {t, First@ρ, Last@ρ}, 
Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

The values of `δβ/δρ` you can find using `fun'[t]`

```
fun'[#] & /@ ρ
```

> {-0.292927, -0.20972, -0.049016, -0.115988, -0.030338}

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This can be accomplished just using Differences and / which will act componentwise. The points and the slopes can be plotted.

```
grad=Differences[\[Beta]]/Differences[\[Rho]];
data=Thread[{\[Rho], \[Beta]}];
slopes=Thread[{Mean@# & /@ Partition[\[Rho], 2, 1], grad}];
ListPlot[{data,slopes},Joined -> True, 
Epilog -> {{Red, Point[data]},{Black,Point[slopes]}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to get the slopes.

```
D[Interpolation[\[Beta], t], t]/D[Interpolation[\[Rho], t], t];
Plot[%, {t, 2, 5}]
```

[image]

The values seem to jive with what is expected from the plot of $\beta$ and $\rho$. The negative slopes should gradually decrease in magnitude.

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{\[Rho], \[Beta]}]]
```

[image]